# Laravel 5.1 | CSRF Protection - safe enough?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, sql-injection, csrf

I'm using csrf protection by default in my website. There are some forms across the website which allow users to send data to DB (like comments).

As much as you know - csrf protection is enough to prevent attacks and injections?

Comment: CSRF protection will not protect you from SQL injections. It's like a doorman; it just checks the identities of the requests before they go into the club, but once they're in, it's not the doormans job to make sure they do no harm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) token** is enough to prevent CSRF attack - see some more details about that attack here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

There are various other threats that need to be handled separately - you can read about most popular attacks here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top10#OWASP_Top_10_for_2013

Laravel has built-in measures against other popular types of attacks as well. Output is by default escaped, which should prevent **XSS** attack. Queries that you do with **Eloquent** are also protected against **SQL injection** attack.

Comment: Well, it seems it will help me. Thank you!